# Listing vectors in span $\{u_1,u_2\}$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

List all vectors in span $\{u_1,u_2\}$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$, where addition and subtraction is done using mod 2 arithmetic.

$u_1 =(1,0,1,0,1)$ and $u_2 = (0,1,1,1,1)$

I am not too sure about how to make a start. From intuition, I think there will be a total of 4 vectors since there are only two numbers: $0, 1$.

Comment: Just compute $0, u_1, u_2,$ and $u_1+u_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right we have also

- $u_3=u_1+u_2=(1,1,0,1,0)$
- $u_4=(0,0,0,0)$